# Resize image without DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, html

I just wrote a [little script](https://gist.github.com/mnbayazit/efd4ba5cd4d73e5530ad) that resizes uploaded images into canvas thumbnails. While resizing images it slows down the rest of the web page.

I just discovered [web workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers) which I was hoping I could use to alleviate this problem by moving the resizing task into the [background](https://gist.github.com/mnbayazit/efd4ba5cd4d73e5530ad#file-resize_image-js).

The MDN article says you can't access the DOM, which is fine, but I was hoping I could still *create* DOM elements and pass a canvas back.

However, the `Image` object doesn't even seem to exist from inside my worker thread. Chrome tells me:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Image is not defined resize_image.js:4

So... is there a way to do this without using those elements? I just want to manipulate the image data and then pass it back to the main thread in a usable form. I don't really care about the DOM elements themselves, but I'm not sure if the JS API gives me any other options?

---

My current resize method, which requires access to DOM elements:

```
resizeImage: function(file, width, height, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (fileLoadEvent) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var srcX = 0, srcY = 0, srcWidth = img.width, srcHeight = img.height, ratio=1;

            var srcRatio = img.width/img.height;
            var dstRatio = width/height;
            if(srcRatio < dstRatio) {
                ratio = img.width/width;
                srcHeight = height*ratio;
                srcY = (img.height-srcHeight)/2;
            } else {
                ratio = img.height/height;
                srcWidth = width*ratio;
                srcX = (img.width-srcWidth)/2;
            }

            var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(this, srcX, srcY, srcWidth, srcHeight, 0, 0, width, height);

            callback(canvas);
        };
        img.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
},
```

Comment: Better if you actually post that "little script" here as well as a demo.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer: "little script" is hyperlinked, but I'll copy it into the question if it makes you happy. I didn't find it completely pertinent as it's kind of useless as written (uses DOM elements). Working demo is a bit hard to provide as my local setup is quite complex and I'm not sure of any fiddles that allow XHR file uploads.

Comment: You may want to look at the answer here, but basically, you may be have a problem as webworkers communicates back by copying, not by reference: https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image/issues/2. For more info look at "Passing Data" at this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_web_workers

Comment: Looks like Chrome 17 and FF 18 both support transferable objects (http://goo.gl/Tjtjx), so I don't think the file-copying is an issue anymore. Lack of DOM elements is still a road block, however.